# Visual Basic: How can I get all selected Values from a Listbox (Selectionmode Multisimple) using a Loop?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, dataset

I'm using a Listbox in my program which is coupled to a dataset. Now I want to select some items in Runtime and get all the values behind those selected items. The values represent the ID's from the Database Entities. I need them for some SQL-queries.

So this is what I've already tried:

```
For x = 0 To ContracttypeListBox.Items.Count() - 1
    If ContracttypeListBox.GetSelected(x) = True Then

        MsgBox(ContracttypeListBox.SelectedItems(x)(ContracttypeListBox.ValueMember))

    End If
Next
```

I found the **function** in the MsgBox using my friend Google. Actually it works quite well but only if I select all items (starting with the first one) in the Listbox. An unselected item among them will cause a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`. The same Problem occurs when I don't select the first item in the list but all the others.

Comment: you are indexing one control's items but looking at another's.  why not just loop thru `ContracttypeListBox.SelectedItems`?  What does `VertragstypListBox` have to do with anything?

Comment: I've changed the like you said. The Exception is gone now but it still have to select the first item to get the other values (like a chainreaction)

Comment: `if myListBx.SelectedItems.Count >0 then....`  if there is nothing selected, there is nothing to iterate and nothing to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Plutonix

This is the solution:

```
    For x = 0 To ContracttypeListBox.SelectedItems.Count() - 1
        If ContracttypeBox.SelectedItems.Count() > 0 Then

            MsgBox(ContracttypeListBox.SelectedItems(x)(ContracttypeListBox.ValueMember))

        End If
    Next x
```

Comment: On a side note, doing MsgBox inside a loop is never a solution, regardless of the problem.

Comment: as a matter of interest: Not even if just use it instead of Console.writeline() ? so just for seeing the Output.

Comment: You could use [Debug.Print](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9azyssyh(v=vs.110).aspx) for debugging/troubleshooting. Running an interactive prompt inside loops is a red flag to reconsider design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ListBox.SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
For Each item In ListBox1.SelectedItems
    Dim id As Integer = Val(item.ToString)
Next
```

Comment: "System.ArgumentException" is thrown. Can't cast a Prompt to String.

Comment: i've tried this but all i get is "System.Data.DataRowView" depends on how many items i select.